# Как раздавить главного персонажа в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, физика

Нужно раздавить главного персонажа, к примеру, камнем или лопастями, но я не знаю как считать давление на `rigidbody2d`. Формулы из физики для подсчёта давления не подходят, т.к. они работают только в идеальных условиях.

Вот [отрывок из игры Badland для примера](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hOq0nRRmqMM).

Comment: В представленном вами ролике персонажа "физически" никто и не давит. Вероятнее всего там идет просчет на то, если персонажа касается ландшафт с двух сторон (лопасти и потолок/пол) в течении какого-то времени (1 секунды, к примеру), то уничтожаем персонажа (заменяем его на анимацию с разлетающимися в разные стороны частицами).

Comment: Определись, ты его убить хочешь или деформировать и оставить таким?

Comment: Убить. Мне нужно узнать силу которая давит на объект. Т.е. если, к примеру, на него упадет доска, то ему ничего не будет, а если очень тяжелый камень, то уничтожить его.

Comment: @СергейГриненко еще раз повторюсь, что ни в каком давлении здесь нет необходимости. Вы можете просто определять столкновение для каждого объекта с игроком: если это **камень** -> **120 ед. урона**, если это **доска** -> **ничего не будет**, если это **топор** -> **убить**, и т.д.

Comment: @ThePyzhov это не подойдет, т.к. есть некоторые ситуации, в которых этот метод будет работать неправильно. К примеру, если камень упадет на какой-то другой камень поменьше и одновременно зацепит персонажа. В реальности давление на персонажа в таком случае будет недостаточным для смерти.